# How is Realtime Database used in dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs sample?

Tags: actions-on-google

It's my second day playing around with Actions on Google, Dialogflow and Firebase, and I got a little confused about the dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs sample(https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs).

The document says it's a sample using real-time database, but I can't see any explicit way of using any database... Is userStorage actually an implicit way of using real-time database? I want to share some data (short text) with a non-actions-on-google application, is there any way to retrieve the data stored in userStorage without the actions-on-google library?

Comment: Can you specify which document you're saying uses the real-time database? Is something in the documentation out of date?

Comment: @Nick [This one](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/assistant-firebase-services) The last sentence of the last section says "Check out [this](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs) sample which uses Firebase Realtime Databases ". As Prisoner has pointed out, the latest version of this example does not use Realtime DB anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the most recent version doesn't use the real-time database, since they replaced it with the userStorage field in the app object.

If you look at an [older version](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-name-psychic-nodejs/tree/904b86e8f2491be6b403e0ae29b6b81e3ce0e0bb), you can see how it uses the real-time database to store user information. (Note that some of the code also uses the older Actions on Google v1 API, so you'll need to jump between versions to really understand how to do it these days.)

In short, however, you have a block that initializes the firebase-admin library:

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

and another block that tries to get the value from a reference in the db based on the user id. If there is a value there, it uses it, otherwise it requests permission:

```
  firebaseAdmin.database().ref('users/' + encodeAsFirebaseKey(userId))
    .once('value', function (data) {
      if (data && data.val() && data.val()[firebaseKey]) {
        let speechOutput = speechCallback(data.val()[firebaseKey]);
        resolve(app.tell(speechOutput));
      } else {
        resolve(app.askForPermission('To read your mind', permission));
      }
    });
```

(This code is a little odd, imho. the `once()` method returns a promise, so wrapping it this way isn't necessary. I would have just done something like:

```
return firebaseAdmin.database()
  .ref('users/' + encodeAsFirebaseKey(userId))
  .once('value')
  .then( data => {
    if (data && data.val() && data.val()[firebaseKey]) {
      let speechOutput = speechCallback(data.val()[firebaseKey]);
      return app.tell(speechOutput);
    } else {
      return app.askForPermission('To read your mind', permission);
    }
  });
```

but I haven't tested this code.)

Finally, at a later point, it saves the information against a reference based on the user ID:

```
  // Save [User ID]:[{<name or location>: <data>}] to Firebase
  // Note: Users can reset User ID at any time.
  firebaseAdmin.database().ref('users/' + encodeAsFirebaseKey(userId)).update({
    [firebaseKey]: userData
  });
```